# What is the value of the following infinite series?

Tags: contest-math, problem-solving

Evaluate the following expression:
$$\frac{2016}{\pi}[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos^{-1}\frac{n^2+n+3}{\sqrt{n^2+3}\sqrt{n^2+2n+4}}]$$

**note**-  I can only tell that the presence of cosine inverse function can imply that we can use any geometric ideas and the dot product to arrive at the solution but certainly no geometric figure comes to my mind to solve this problem. So please can anyone suggest any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

First, we notice that
$$\begin{align}
\frac{n^2+n+3}{\sqrt{n^2+3}\sqrt{n^2+2n+4}} &= \frac{n(n+1)+3}{\sqrt{n^2+3}\sqrt{(n+1)^2+3}}\\
&=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+3}}\cdot \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+3}}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{n^2+3}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+3}}
\end{align}$$
Second, try to apply the formula
$$\cos(x-y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y)$$
with
$$\cos(x) = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+3}}$$
$$\cos(y) = \frac{n+1}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+3}}$$

and you deduce easily that
$$\begin{align}
S &= \frac{2016}{\pi}\left(\arccos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1^2+3}} \right) -\arccos\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2^2+3}}\right)+\arccos\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2^2+3}}\right) -... \right)\\
&= \frac{2016}{\pi} \cdot  \arccos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1^2+3}} \right)=\frac{2016}{\pi} \cdot \frac{\pi}{3} = 672
\end{align}$$

Comment: You have the wrong sign for $\cos(x-y)$

Comment: @jjagmath just a typo, I corrected it.